# Google API Authentication for App That Only Accesses One Account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication, service-accounts

**Should I use a Service Account or an OAuth 2.0 Client ID?**

I'm struggling to understand Google's documentation on authenticating for their APIs. I'm creating a basic application that will help users add and modify Google Calendar events for a single Google account (the account is shared between all users). I only need the application to access that one account, it'll never need to access any others.

It seems to me that Service Account would be best for this, but Google's documentation suggests Service Accounts should only be used for automated processes (unless I'm misunderstanding). For instance [this page contains the following](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/how-to-authenticate-service-accounts-to-help-keep-applications-secure?authuser=1), describing when to use Service Accounts.

[image: Ask yourself if you need a service account]

Would my application qualify as acting on the users behalf?

If so, I would want to use OAuth Client ID credentials, which will ask the user to sign in to a google account. In this case, is there a way I can guarantee they only sign in to the one account I want modified?

I can't find any decent documentation on the OAuth authentication requests to figure this out myself. If there is any could you point me there?

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something basic here, but thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should know that you can only use service accounts with Google aclendar api if you have a google workspace domain account.

You can then set up a calendar and a domain user that the service account can act on behalf of to control the access of that calendar.

Assuming that your application is going to preform all actions on this calendar then yes i would say that you could use a service account for this.   If your app bacly has a ui with a calendar on it your just using google calendar to store the data.

However if you intend to share this calendar with the users themselves, this way they could see it within their own google Calendar account.  Im not sure a service account would be the way to go.

If you want the users to be able to see it and make changes then you may want to just use Oauth2.  Grant them access to the calendar and then request access to their calendar account.

Drawback to that option is going to be the verification process.  You will get access to all the users calendars and your going to need write access.

If you can go with a service account you really should consider it it will save you a lot of hassle with verification.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up a lot! Given that we don't have a google workspace domain account and don't plan to create one, it seems Oauth is the way to go (I'd still like them to be able to make changes directly to the calendar anyways). Is there any documentation you could point me to for extra settings there? I.e. I know you can add `prompt=select_account` as a parameter in the url. Are there any other ways to help ensure users log in to the correct account? I just want to make sure I don't modify the wrong calendar.

Comment: The issue you are going to have with Oauth2 is that the user must have access to the calendar. You will need to share the calendar with the user, then they will be able to see it in the web version of google calendar.  When they run your app you will need to request consent for your app to access their calendars, including the one you just shared with them.  It will also give you access to all of the users calendars.   You will need a write scope which will be a sensitive scope.   Verification of the app will be more time consuming using a sensitive scope.

Comment: I don't think prompt does what you think it does.  Its going to let prompt the user to login to their own google account.

Comment: Sorry I may not have explained this very well unless I'm still not understanding you. The google calendar is for a small business and they're using it to display rental status of a few items. The users are logging into the business' google account and manually modifying events to display the info. I'm just hoping to create an app to streamline this process for them. So the calendar already exists and does not need to be shared with their personal accts, they just need to log in using the business' account. I just want to ensure they always select the business acct and not their personal acct.

Comment: Regarding the prompt. I'm not saying I need to use it, but I just found that via some other SO questions. I'm just curious if there's any documentation anywhere that describes prompt and any other parameters that may exist, if there are any.

Comment: **users are logging into the business** It is against googles tos to share login to a google account.   One user one google account.   Small business should probably be using workspace and not a standard gmail google login.   Docs for Open Id connect [Prompt](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#re-consent)

Comment: I was not aware of that, thank you. I'll let them know and we can look into using workspace. That answers all my questions though. Thanks for all your help DaImTo!